# Create Read Stream from remote location in node

Tags: node.js, filestream

I'm trying to pull a csv file from a remote url in node and use [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson/)
to parse it. I am using the request library to get the file but cannot turn it into a readable stream so that I can send it into csvtojson. Sorry this is typescript but it should be interpretable.
If I do the following

```
request.get("http://myurl.com", (err, response, body) => {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Something that looks like the file gets printed out but I can't turn it into a writable stream. It certainly isn't anything I can send into csvtojson.
I know you can create a writestream like this.

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

But that doesn't do me a whole lot of good since I just want to get the csv and parse it rather than write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its documentation, `csvtojson` supports streams (there are examples of it in the docs). So you would just do something like:

```
var request = require('request');
var Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter;

request('http://example.org/foo.csv')
  .pipe(new Converter({constructResult:true}))
  .on('end_parsed', function(jsonObj) {
    console.dir(jsonObj);
  });
```

Comment: I attempted this exact answer with constructResult set to false but it didn't work for me. It turns out that when constructResult is set to false it will return an empty object which made me think nothing had been piped to the function. Thank You!